# Erlang Worker Process

Tags: erlang, message, message-passing

I'm pretty new to Erlang, however I've been trying to create a simple client server implementation. The server would hypothetically create worker processes to do "heavy work" in a "database" and then return the calculated values to the client.

My current steps are:

1. Create a server process.
2. Spawn a worker.
3. Send the worker some work to do based off the clients input. **(Here's where I'm confused)**
4. Send the data from the worker back to the client.

Here is some sample code.

```
-module(server).
-compile(export_all).

server() ->
    receive
        {From, {client, Name}} ->
            io:format("Server has received request for ~p from ~p~n", [Name, From]),
            Worker = spawn(server, getNameFromDataBase(self()),[]),
            Worker ! Name,
            From ! LastName,%%data returned from worker
            server();
        {database, LastName} ->
            Data = LastName,
            server()
    end.


getNameFromDataBase(Server_Address) ->
    receive
        {name, Name} ->
            timer:sleep(5000), %doing difficult work!
            Server_Address ! {database, "Johnson"}
    end.



client(Server_Address) ->
    Server_Address ! {self(), {client, "Jim"}},
    receive
            {server, LastName} ->
                io:format("Server got person's last name~p~n", LastName)
    end.
```

How do you make it so that the data you receive from the worker will be seen and be able to be sent to the client?

Answer (score 3):

I can see you have two main problems on the server process:

1. Sending message from the server to the database worker.
2. Sending message that the server received from worker back to the client.

**Sending message to the worker**

Your following lines of code from L8 - L10 is incorrect.

```
%% ...
Worker = spawn(server, getNameFromDataBase(self()), []),
Worker ! Name,                                           
From ! LastName,                   
%% ...
```

To spawn a function as a process, you must provide any argument(s) to the function as members of the list in the third argument of `spawn/3`, not call the function directly.

```
Worker = spawn(server, getNameFromDataBase, [self()]),
```

Sending only `Name` to `Worker` will go unnoticed since `getNameFromDataBase` expects `{name, Name}`. This should be changed to

```
Worker ! {name, Name}
```

**Sending result (LastName) to the client**

It doesn't make sense to send `From ! LastName` on L10 since you have not received `LastName`. This should be moved to the second match expression when the server have received `{database, LastName}` from the worker. 
Additionally, the `client` expects `{server, LastName}`, not `LastName`. So it was supposed to be `From ! {server, LastName}`.

However, there's a problem. You cannot get access to `From` in that scope because it was never defined.

```
%% ...
{database, LastName} ->
    From ! {server, LastName},      % `From` is not defined
    server()
%% ...
```

What you may want to do without having to change the message tuple is to define another `server/1` function like so:

```
server(ClientPID) ->
    receive
        {_, LastName} ->
            ClientPID ! {server, LastName},
            server()
    end.
```

and call this from `server/0`:

```
server() ->
    receive
        {From, {client, Name}} ->
            io:format("Server has received request for ~p from ~p~n", [Name, From]),
            Worker = spawn(?MODULE, getNameFromDataBase, [self()]),
            Worker ! {name, Name},
            server(From)      % call `server/1` with the client's PID
    end.
```

Finally, to wrap everything up, if you haven't already, create an initiating function to spawn the `server` and `client` processes. Here is the completed code:

```
server() ->
    receive
        {From, {client, Name}} ->
            io:format("Server has received request for ~p from ~p~n", [Name, From]),
            Worker = spawn(?MODULE, getNameFromDataBase, [self()]),
            Worker ! {name, Name},
            server(From)
    end.

server(ClientPID) ->
    receive
        {_, LastName} ->
            ClientPID ! {server, LastName},
            server()
    end.

getNameFromDataBase(ServerAddr) ->
    receive
        {name, Name} ->
            io:format("worker received ~p~n",[Name]),
            timer:sleep(5000),
            ServerAddr ! {database, "Johnson"}
    end.

client(ServerPID) ->
    ServerPID ! {self(),{client, "Jim"}},
    receive
        {server, LastName} ->
            io:format("Client got person's last name ~p from Server ~n", [LastName])
    end.

run() ->
    ServerPID = spawn(?MODULE, server, []),
    spawn(?MODULE, client, [ServerPID]).
```

Last tip: Do not use `export_all` compile option. Only export the necessary functions for good encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the message from the worker in the `{database, LastName} ->` branch of the receive. Just include the information you need to handle it in the message itself:

```
server() ->
    receive
        {From, {client, Name}} ->
            io:format("Server has received request for ~p from ~p~n", [Name, From]),
            Worker = spawn(server, getNameFromDataBase, [self()]),
            Worker ! {name, From, Name},
            server();
        {database, From, LastName} ->
            From ! LastName,
            server()
    end.

getNameFromDataBase(Server_Address) ->
    receive
        {name, From, Name} ->
            timer:sleep(5000), %doing difficult work!
            Server_Address ! {database, From, "Johnson"}
    end.
```

Note that the arguments need to be passed in the list (third argument of `spawn`). Also if you create the worker just to send a single message immediately you can just as well pass its content as arguments; I didn't make this change here to make it easier to see the main change.

Alternately, you can store the `From` corresponding to `Worker` in server state (argument to `server()`).

Comment: In this case the client expects `{server, LastName}` so sending just `LastName` with `From ! LastName` won't print anything.